# Is it possible to set timezone when aggregate using time window of 24 hours

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I want aggregate some value using time window of 24 hours, it works ok, but the time window from 00:00 to 23:59 of utc time, is it possible to set timezone so that the time window start and end of my local time (Beijing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently (Kafka 2.0), there is no timezone support. What you can do is, to modify, ie, shift, the timestamps before handing them into the `aggregation()` and shift them back afterwards.

Depending on your application, for input data (won't not work for output, ie, shifting back) you might be able to use a custom `TimestampExtractor`.

You can also use a `transfrom()` operator. In `context.forward(...)` you can set the timestamp accordingly (ie, shift forward/backward) via third parameter `To.all().withTimestamp(...)`.

Comment: great!  it works for me. I add a custom `TimestampExtractor ` and solved the problem :)